# Why recyclerView isn't updating

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

Hello guys I'm using ViewModel and Livedata to display movies. It is working for the popular movies but when I try to change the sorting from the menu it doesn't show anything... here is my MainActivity: 
ps: if Irecreate the activity it works fine.
Here is my gist: https://gist.github.com/kaizoku-619/d7ced8453bb686e8fbdb65a635ff504b

Comment: share your code bro , then i will understand your problem.

Comment: For what I can see, you're not calling your sortBy method on the onOptionsItemSelected()

Comment: @VishalSharma the code is in the gist repo in the link

Comment: @user8886048 I tried to call it from the onOptionsItemSelected() but its not workin g either

Comment: Does it give you any errors? Is the screen just empty or it just doesn't sort the list?

Comment: You wouldn't need to call adapter.setMovieList() either, because your sortBy replaces the adapter as soon as the list is ready on the observer's onChanged

Comment: @user8886048 when I first start the app it works fine and shows a list of popular movies but when I try to change the sorting from the menu the list becomes blank and it doesn't show any errors

Comment: @user8886048 I tried this but it doesn't work either

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                sort = "popular";
                sortBy(sort);
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                sort = "top_rated";
                sortBy(sort);
                return true;
            case R.id.item3:
                sort = "favorite";
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }